# Vertex/Fragment Shader using Xcode output a syntax error

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm following a tutorial on shader done using Visual Studio...  I'm using Xcode on ElCapitan.

My readShaderCode() function pass the shaderCode files content ( vertex.glsl and fragment.glsl ) to the console --just to make sure-- along with the OpenGL version .

So this code works on Windows but not on my machine !  I can't see what the problem is and if somebody could figure it out for me I would really appreciate it! Thanks.  And thanks for all the posts that have been helping me along for sometimes now :)

Here is the output:

```
    Working with OpenGl: 2.1 INTEL-10.14.66

    Here is the shader Code: 
    #version 120
    #extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

    in layout(location=0) vec2 position;
    in layout(location=1) vec3 vertexColor;

    out vec3 theColor;

    void main() {

        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);

        theColor = vertexColor;

    }

    *****************************************
    Working with OpenGl: 2.1 INTEL-10.14.66

    Here is the shader Code: 
    #version 120
    #extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

    out vec4 daColor; 
    in vec3 theColor; 

    void main() { 


    daColor = vec4(theColor, 1.0); 


    } 

    *****************************************
    WARNING: 0:2: extension 'GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects' is not                 supported
    ERROR: 0:4: '(' : syntax error: syntax error
```

Answer (score 3):

You get perfectly reasonable errors and warnings.

> WARNING: 0:2: extension 'GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects' is not                 supported

That means exactly what it says. Your shader depends on an extension that isn't supported.

> ERROR: 0:4: '(' : syntax error: syntax error

There is only one `(` character in line 4 of your vertex shader, so that makes it clear what the problem is.

This:

> ```
> in layout(location=0) vec2 position;
> ```

Is *not valid* GLSL 1.20 code. GLSL 1.20 does not permit `in` qualified global variables, and GLSL 1.20 has no idea what `layout` means.

Your code is not reasonable GLSL code of the `#version` it is declared with. If another implementation took it, then you were relying on implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Ok.   Thanks Nicol